# Приемочное тестирование добавления записи в таблицу неизвестного размера

Tags: codeception, acceptance-tests

Есть, допустим, список, в который можно добавить запись. Если список содержит более 20 записей то появляется пагинатор. Предполагается что тест на добавление/удаление может быть запущен на сервере с разными данными. Тест нужно написать на codeception. Так вот, есть ли у него в приемочных тестах проверка на существование элемента на странице, чтобы можно было создать условие? Например "если есть пагинатор то кликнуть на последнюю страницу". Как выбрать куда кликнуть разобраться легко, а вот как проверить существование и в зависимости от проверки выполнять определённые действия? $I->seeElement('.pagination') не возвращает true, он просто говорит что "да есть", но в if не полезет.

Answer (score 0):

Покачто костыльнул так, если кому интересно - 

`public function lastPage(AcceptanceTester $I, $count){
       $tr = $I->grabMultiple('.table > tbody > tr');
       if (count($tr) == $count) {
           $I->seeElement('.pagination');
           $pagination = $I->grabMultiple('.pagination > li');
           $page = count($pagination) - 1;
           $I->click('.pagination > li:nth-child('.$page.') > a:nth-child(1)');
       }
   }`

Добавил эту функцию в хэлпер.
$count - это число вмещающихся записей на странице до появления пагинации.